# Authentication with case insensitive username

Tags: python, django

I have created login model in Django and I am using `username` for authentication(using default `authenticate()`), but at present the `username` is case-sensitive. Is there a way in django that while authenticating the case-sensitivity of `username` is not considered?

Answer (score 3):

You could lowercase or uppercase the username when someone register or login.

First get the data from the form:

`username = login_form.cleaned_data.get('user_username')`

`password = login_form.cleaned_data.get('user_password')`

After that lowercase the username:

`username = username.lower()`

Then authenticate:

`user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)`

Remember to lowercase the username in the register form too.

Comment: But what if one wants to login with uppercase username

Comment: If someone types an uppercase you will lowercase that username. And when a user is registering in the platform you will save the username in lowercase. 

The user can type an uppercase username but internally you always can work with a lowercase username.